# Excel file upload

Tags: c#, excel, object, asp-classic

i need to upload an excel file to the server. but the thing is dat i need to     check     whether this has **MS Excel 12.0 object library**  or not?? can anyone suggest mean           method  for this..??

Comment: You want to check whether the SERVER has that library?  Last I checked, Excel is not licensed for use on a server (and in fact will not run well under any significant volume).

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `c#` and `asp-classic` at the same time? Any relation? And obviously the eternal question stands: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do - my advice is simple - you DONT want to go take that route. See this link - Considerations for server-side Automation of Office: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 0):

Here is some classic ASP code once the Excel file has been uploaded to the server ([copied from here](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/classic-asp-read-excel-file-into-recordset-141448.html)).

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<html>
<body>
<%
Dim objConn, objRS, strSQL
Dim x, curValue

Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}; IMEX=1; HDR=NO; "&_
    "Excel 8.0; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("excelfile.xls") & "; "

'if using xslx (Excel 2007) use this instead:
'objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};"&_
'   "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("excelfile.xlsx") & ";"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM A1:Q10000"
Set objRS=objConn.Execute(strSQL)
Response.Write("<table border=""1"">")
Response.Write("<tr>")
For x=0 To objRS.Fields.Count-1
   Response.Write("<th>" & objRS.Fields(x).Name & "</th>")
Next
Response.Write("</tr>")
Do Until objRS.EOF
    Response.Write("<tr>")
    For x=0 To objRS.Fields.Count-1
        curValue = objRS.Fields(x).Value
        If IsNull(curValue) Then
            curValue="N/A"
        End If
        curValue = CStr(curValue)
        Response.Write("<td>" & curValue & "</td>")
    Next
    Response.Write("</tr>")
    objRS.MoveNext
Loop
objRS.Close
Response.Write("</table>")
objConn.Close
Set objRS=Nothing
Set objConn=Nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```